# Derivative of a separable function of a matrix with respect to a matrix

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

Let $W_1\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}, W_2\in\mathbb{R}^{1\times n}, x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and consider the function

$$H(W_1, W_2, x) = W_2 F(W_1x)$$
with $F\colon \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ some differentiable function that acts component-wise (its Jacobian $D$ is diagonal).

Since, as a function of $W_1$, $H$ maps from $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\to\mathbb{R}$, the derivative should be an $n\times n$ matrix. I am trying to compute this derivative of this function with respect to $W_1$. What I have so far is the following:

$$\partial_{W_1} (W_2 F(W_1 x)) = \partial_{W_1}F(W_1x)\times W_2^T = \partial_{W_1}(W_1x)\times D^T\times W_2^T$$

What am I doing wrong/where to go from here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\op{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
$Rather than subscripts, let's give each variable a unique name. Let's also adopt a convention wherein upppercase letters denote matrices, lowercase vectors, and Greek letters will be scalars. We'll also represent vectors as columns by default. For row vectors, use a transpose operation.

Define/rename the variables
$$\eqalign{
W &= W_1 \\
v &= W_2^T \\
y &= Wx &\qiq dy = dW\,x \\
f &= f(y) &\qiq df = J\,dy,\quad J = \grad fy \\
\phi &= H \\
}$$
and use a colon to denote the matrix inner product product
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \frob{A}^2 \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\;norm} \}\\
A:B &= B:A \;=\; B^T:A^T \\
\LR{AB}:C &= A:\LR{CB^T} \;=\; B:\LR{A^TC} \\
}$$
With the above tools we can differentiate the scalar-valued function
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= v:f \\
d\phi &= v:df \\
 &= v:J\,dy \\
 &= J^Tv:dy \\
 &= J^Tv:\LR{dW\,x} \\
 &= J^Tvx^T:dW \\
\grad{\phi}W &= J^Tvx^T \\
}$$

### Update

Rereading the question, I see that $f(y)$ is an elementwise function.

In that case we need a bit more notation. When applied to a scalar argument $(z)$, the function and its derivative are
$$\eqalign{
f=f(z), \qquad f'=f'(z) \qiq df = f'\,dz \\
}$$
When applied elementwise to a vector argument the functions become vector-valued
$$\eqalign{
f &= f(y), \qquad f'= f'(y) \qiq df = f'\odot dy \\
}$$
where $\odot$ is the elementwise/Hadamard product, which can be replaced with a diagonal matrix
$$\eqalign{
F = \Diag{f},\quad F' = \Diag{f'} \qiq df = F'\,dy \\
}$$
So substitute $F'$ for $J\LR{{\rm and}\ J^T}$ in the previous calculation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, greg. Do you have a recommandation on a book that explains the general process you've followed with the $d$ operator? Preferably one that also covers the case for maps from $\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}\to\mathbb{R}^{p\times q}$?

Comment: The standard text is probably Magnus and Neudecker's *Matrix Differential Calculus*
although personally I prefer Hjorungnes's *Complex-Valued Matrix Derivatives*

Comment: Thanks, can you be more specific about which chapters or sections are relevant to this reasoning? And why do you prefer the latter book, is it just because it covers the complex case? If you didn't have any need for complex-valued objects would you prefer the first book then?

Comment: Magnus and Neudecker contains 17 chapters. Chapters 4 - 10 deal with differentials like those shown above. Their general prescription for dealing with $\frac{\partial F}{\partial X}$ is to flatten both $F\ {\rm and}\ X$ into vectors using the $\operatorname{vec}$ operation.  Hjorungnes tends not to flatten anything, and also deals with complex matrices (using Wirtinger derivatives).